# Get field value in an entity form validation

Tags: forms

In an entityform "form_alter" function I have $form_state with all the info inside I need.
I could "hard-code" the language, but this is a multi language site...
The information needed is at: `$form_state['values']['field_myone']['en'][0]['value']`

I'm aware of field_get_items or entity_metadata_wrapper, but I can't get either one to work.

This doesn't give me a wrapper back:

```
$wrap = entity_metadata_wrapper('entity_form', $form_state);
```

And this one doesn't work either:

```
$val = field_get_items('entityform', $form_state, 'field_myone');
```

Any help out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested. Please post the answer if you solved.

This code:

```
$node = node_load($form_state['node']->nid;);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node, array('bundle', $node->type));
```

solves in case you are editing a previously saved node (and the `nid` is then existing).